# If $m(X)<\infty$ and $f$ bounded and measurable, then $1\leq q<p<\infty$ implies $\|f\|_{p}^{p}\leq\|f\|_{q}^{q}\|f\|_{\infty}^{p-q}.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

$\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $m(X)<\infty$ and $f$ bounded and measurable. For $1\leq q<p<\infty$ prove that $\|f\|_{p}^{p}\leq\|f\|_{q}^{q}\|f\|_{\infty}^{p-q}.$

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ At first sight I was trying to somehow bring in Holder's inequality here, but I got nowhere. So I observed that the result would follow if it is true that
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|_\infty}\right)^p\leq\left(\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|_\infty}\right)^q\text{ for almost every }x\in X.$$
Now I fix $x\in X$ for which the above is true, and observe that
$$\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|_\infty}\leq1.$$
Since the function
$$\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|_\infty}\mapsto\left(\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|_\infty}\right)^z$$
decreases monotonically, the result follows.

---

Is my line of reasoning on the right track?

My apologies if my wording is bad. If it is though, please point out, and I will do my best to correct it.

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Hint: $\|f\|_p^p=\int_X |f|^p\,d\mu=\int_X |f|^{p-q}|f|^q\,d\mu$

Comment: @Cuoredicervo Thank you for the hint, I see it now. I made this much harder than it really was.

Comment: @GtheStackman If you've now solved it then it is good practice here to write an answer to your own question.